# Separating/Decoupling AsyncTask and UI-Thread

Tags: android

Is there any way to separate the UI-Thread and the AsyncTask?  I would like to execute the AsyncTask, register some Method and simply wait. If the AsyncTask finishes I would like that the UI-Threads starts a Function which simply fills the Data from the AsyncTask into the Forms.

One way would be using Broadcasts, but that seems a bit overkill for me. Is there no other way to seperate the Logic and the UI?  I know that there is `protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed result)` but that would is in the AsyncTask-Class so UI-Logic and Backgroundlogic is mixed again.

I ask this because in C# its very easy to accomplish this, just add an Event and I personally find it very chique if a good separation is existent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a separate custom [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html), and pass a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) when you instantiate it. When the thread finish, let it call the handler.